# Joining table using bridge

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
    Courses         Teachers        Students        StudentCourses
    CourseID        TeacherID       StudentID       CourseID
    CourseName      TeacherName     StudentName     StudentID
    TeacherID
```

Hello,
These are my tables, I have two problems..

1. I need to get list of all students AND how many courses each has enrolled in
2. All students enrolled in course started with "Art".

I am confused, because of the `StudentCourses` table. Thank you in advance!

1.

```
SELECT *
FROM Students s
INNER JOIN StudentCourses sc
ON  s.StudentID =  sc.StudentID
UNION
SELECT COUNT(courseID)
FROM StudentCourses dd
INNER JOIN Student ss
ON ss.studentID = dd.studentID
GROUP BY studentID
```

Is `JOIN` suitable in this case?

2.

```
SELECT *
FROM Students s
JOIN StudentCourses sc
ON  s.StudentID =  sc.StudentID
JOIN Courses c
ON sc.COurseID = c.CourseID
WHERE CourseName = ‘Art%’
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Well, what have you tried?  StudentCourses links a student to a course, so you need to join on that for your scenarios.

Comment: The StudentCourses table is there to enforce the many-to-many relationship there is between students and courses. 1 student can have many courses, 1 course can have many students. By splitting out the relationship into 2 tables, you now have 1 student_course row matches to one student row and 1 course row. What you need to do is write a query that joins the students, studentcourses and courses tables. Then you can amend that query as necessary to answer your questions. If you get stuck, edit your question to show what you've tried so far and we'll be able to guide you further.

Comment: (In fact, for your first question, you can probably get away with just joining the Students and StudentCourses tables together)

Comment: @OldProgrammer ill update my current attempt now.

Comment: And i think I need to count total courses per student enrolled @Boneist

Comment: @user6185827 `JOIN` (or better, `INNER JOIN` - this is more informative of your intentions, IMHO) is absolutely the right thing to use here. If you have 1 student and 2 courses, and the student only took one of the courses, how many rows are you expecting your query to get back? One, right? I.e. the row from studentcourses which matched that student's id. For the first question, you don't actually need any information from the courses table, because the studentcourses table will tell you the course ids each student took, and you can simply count those. (Hint, you need an aggregate query here)

Comment: @Boneist so I need to use `INNER JOIN` . Just joining the `student` and `studentcourses`. How about the counting. Im sure I need to use `COUNT()`. However, Idk where i should place it

Comment: I've update my answer for both questions @Boneist. Am i doing them right?

Comment: @user6185827 yes, `INNER JOIN` (which is synonymous with `JOIN`, but more explicit IMHO). A basic aggregate query for looks something like `select grouping_col1, grouping_col2, ...., <aggregate_function>(...) from some_table group by grouping_col1, grouping_col2, ...`. In your case, you want to count how many rows there are per studentid, so your grouping column and aggregate function will be....?

Comment: @user6185827 for your first question, maybe you should do the count against the studentcourses table first, and then you can join that to the students table if you need to output things like the student name, etc

Comment: @user6185827 you're counting the courseids, you're doing it per studentid (so studentid is the column you're grouping by)

Comment: Am i doing it right now? using the `UNION` ... @Boneist

Comment: No, you don't need the union

Comment: Just remove the union and the query does not need anything to bind with? @Boneist

Comment: I've added an answer that will hopefully guide you through the first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first answer, you say you need the list of students (by which I assume you mean you need to output details only available in the Student table, such as name), along with how many courses they have enrolled in.

The second part of this question can be done by counting how many rows there are in the studentcourses table per studentid:

```
SELECT studentid, COUNT(courseID) num_of_enrolled_courses
FROM   studentcourses
GROUP BY studentID;
```

Once you have that, you can simply join this query to the students table to get the extra information:

```
select s.studentname,
       sc.num_of_enrolled_courses
from   studentname s
       inner join (SELECT studentid, COUNT(courseID) num_of_enrolled_courses
                   FROM   studentcourses
                   GROUP BY studentID) sc on s.studentid = sc.studentid;
```

For your second query, you're nearly correct - your filter on the courses table needs to be `CourseName like 'Art%'` (i.e. use `like` not '=' when you're doing a wildcard search). You also need to output just the columns you're interested in, possibly students.studentname and courses.coursename.

Comment: I see. Joining thru the query named as `sc`. I will keep this in mind. Thank you soo much for being patience with me. I need more practices hmm

Comment: No problem *{:-) If you want more practice, you could always read through the #oracle and/or #sql tagged questions on StackOverflow and try to answer them/read through the answers given by other people. AskTom is another good resource.

Comment: @user6185827 - "joining thru the query named `sc`" is right. (Joining "to" is more common, but that's just English). Really, you are joining to the result, or the output, of the query. (Which in this case, when used in the more complex code, is known as a "subquery".) The point is that the output of the subquery is a set of rows. Just like a table. Just like a view. What really matters - what you join, what you select from, etc. is a "sets of rows". In such cases, the output from a subquery is indistinguishable from a stored table. You extracted *exactly* the right conclusion from this Answer.